# condition based lookup in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB, and node.js need help in mongo lookup. I want to join two documents based on a condition. I am using mongoose, node, and express. In the aggregation of a `Conversation` model I want to look up the other model `User`.

This is user1

```
{
    "_id": "0b3bb0bb2d78405fa941dd3e1da9574a",
    "status": true,
    "fullName": "Irtza",
    "mobileNumber": "+9200000000000",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-05-05T11:39:00.875Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-04T11:10:53.103Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
}
```

This is user2

```
{
    "_id": "51701df06d084003853cd0837d76606a",
    "status": true,
    "fullName": "Shehroz Ali",
    "mobileNumber": "+10000000000",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-05-06T11:28:48.980Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-04T12:34:03.676Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
}
```

And there is a conversation between them

```
{
    "_id": "9a4d221ebbde4ba68b28783232aed28c",
    "userIds": ["0b3bb0bb2d78405fa941dd3e1da9574a", "51701df06d084003853cd0837d76606a"],
    "type": "private",
    "conversationName": "abc",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-04T10:46:43.061Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-04T10:46:43.061Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

So base on the above scenario I want to lookup/join a conversation with the user whose Id is not passing to Conversation.

There is a requested `userId` based on `userId` I want to lookup the `User` model. Also in my `Conversation` I have an array of string `"userIds": ["0b3bb0bb2d78405fa941dd3e1da9574a", "51701df06d084003853cd0837d76606a"]` if `userIds.0` match with the `userId` then lookup with `userIds.1` and if `userIds.1` match with the `userId` then lookup with `userIds.0` Here is my code:

```
this.aggregate([
                { $match: { userIds: { $all: [userId] } } },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'users',
                        localField: 'userIds.0',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'user1',
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$user1" },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'users',
                        localField: 'userIds.1',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'user2',
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$user2" },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'messages',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: 'conversationId',
                        as: 'messageBody',
                    }
                },
                { "$addFields": {
                    "messageBody": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [ "$messageBody", -1 ]
                    }
                }},
                { $unwind: "$messageBody" },
            ]);
```

Comment: Can you add an example of Conversation and User documents?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic please check now.

Comment: I posted my answer. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first use `$unwind`, and then `$lookup`. You can do it like this:

- `$match` to filter our Conversations where the requested `userId` is present in `userIds` arrays
- `$unwind` to deconstructs an `userIds` array field
- `$match` again to filter only requested `userId`
- `$lookup` to replace `userId` with actual User document

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "userIds": "0b3bb0bb2d78405fa941dd3e1da9574a"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$userIds"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "userIds": {
        "$ne": "0b3bb0bb2d78405fa941dd3e1da9574a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "userIds",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "userIds"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/I5GyY2XMLkb

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to join that user whose id is not matched in userIds array.

Comment: Can you add your expected output in the question?

Comment: if "0b3bb0bb2d78405fa941dd3e1da9574a" is in request then in response it gave me this user id "51701df06d084003853cd0837d76606a" with user details.

Comment: I see. Then you can just add `$ne`. I updated my answer and working example. Can you check if it works for you?